# Why is jsonb_path_query missing values for some rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have this `jsonb` that I'm trying to flatten and migrate to `conversations` and `tags` tables:

```
{
  id: '1',
  type: 'conversation',
  tags: [
   {
    id: '1',
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'foo'
   }, {
    id: '2',
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'bar'
   },
   {
    id: '3',
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'baz'
   }
  ]
}
```

But the following query is returning unexpected results:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.id') #>> '{}' conversation_id,
    jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.tags[*].name') tag_name
FROM conversations;
```

```
conversation_id | tag_name
1                 foo
                  bar
                  baz
```

I want the following instead

```
conversation_id | tag_name
1                 foo
1                 bar
1                 baz
```

I might be missing something obvious but I'm unclear:

- Why `conversation_id` is `NULL` for the second and third row.
- How I can get the results I want without parsing the `jsonb` in two passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how multiple set-returning functions in the select-list works [since v10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-sql.html).  See not starting "Before PostgreSQL 10, putting more than one set-returning function"

Your query can be converted to the simpler:

```
SELECT 
    payload #>> '{id}' conversation_id,
    jsonb_path_query(payload, '$.tags[*].name') tag_name
FROM conversations;
```